# Tiki shows data times not in my Timezone just in UTC

Tags: datetime, tiki-wiki

When I configure the general setting to use the site timezone for showing date times and also when I set the same setting in the user preferences, tiki shows the times just in UTC timezone.

I tried all combinations of timezone setting in general and user preferences but it still shows UTC timezone.

Is there any suggestion for it?

Answer (score 1):

I think I solved the problem. I found the return from /var/www/html/tikisvn15/lib/core/service/tracker/CalendarController.php is not correct. When performing Unified search function, it returned the time stamps that is NOT UTC/GMT. FullCalendar accepts UTC/GMT to show the correct time. So I did a little modification to the above file:

I added:
`$displayTimeZone = new DateTimeZone($prefs['display_timezone']);
$dateTime = new DateTime("now", $displayTimeZone);
$tzOffset = $displayTimeZone->getOffset($dateTime);`

in the return array, I added:

`'start' => $this->getTimestamp($row[$start]) + $tzOffset,
'end' => $this->getTimestamp($row[$end]) + $tzOffset ,`

It works perfectly for me. I wish I have time to debug further into the unified search but I can't.
Cheer!!

Comment: I checked and the "Detect browser language" wasn't enabled. I enabled it, revert my modification and test. The time showed in the calendar is 4 hours different from the time is set to start.

Comment: I checked and the "Detect browser language" wasn't enabled. I enabled it, revert my modification and test. My user preference is set to "Detect browser..." too. Then I tried again with setting "America/Toronto" in my user preference. The time showed in the calendar is 4 hours different from the time is set to start. However, the tracker display is correct and it has always been with or without the code I did since they use tracker lib to load.
I tried with my php setting in a PHP file (not in Tiki environment). It works. Btw, I have this problem even I upgrade the system 15.4 then 16.2.

Comment: Sorry, I can't comment on your answer. Not enough reputation. ;D

Answer (score 0):

That doesn't sound right, it seems to change ok for me on my Tiki 16.x. Do you have "Detect browser language" enabled (on control panels -> i18n)?

Maybe that's it?

Alternatively maybe a server or PHP setting is overriding what you're setting in Tiki, check the phpinfo for the date.timezone etc settings.

Comment: Thanks @jonnybradley for the reply. I've tested every setting. At first look at this code: ' <?php
$timestamp=1486739334;
echo gmdate("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
echo "<br/>";
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $timestamp);
?> ' And the result is : ' 2017-02-10 15:08:54
2017-02-10 10:08:54 ' It means the settings for the server and php timezone are working. In the tiki I've set the **Displayed time zone
  -> Always the site default time zone.** What should I do?

Comment: Did you ever get this solved? Not sure i have much more to offer...
Which OS is your server running on? Maybe a clue there if it's something unusual (not Debian/Ubuntu/Centos etc)
Can you try and completely new tiki install and see if it does it without and setting changes?

Comment: I found that the timestamp has stored based on UTC in the database and when I try to view a single item Tiki convert it to my timezone properly. But when I use list plugin or trackerCalendar plugin for listing the items it doesn't convert to my timezone! Is there any way for setting timezone for list plugin like in {FORMAT} or etc...? @jonnybradley

Comment: @MajidAkbari I have a feeling the issue in TrackerCalendar was fixed in 16.x and maybe 15.x fairly recently, but before 16.2 was released i think so check you're up to date. For the list plugin are you using the datetime format? i.e. {display name="modification_date" format="datetime"} - i thought that handled timezones properly (i'll try and check some time)